# How do I update multiple Gridviews across multiple User Controls while the Gridviews and User Controls are inside Update Panels?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, user-controls, updatepanel

I have a page with an ASP Place Holder wrapped in an Update Panel on it, I load a single User Control with another Place Holder wrapped in an Update Panel on it. I then load this newest Place Holder with multiple User Controls, each of which contains a Gridview wrapped in an Update Panel.

The data in each Gridview is based on the data in "previous" Gridviews, so when the user edits a row the changes cascade down the Gridviews, this is where my problem lies. After clicking the save button nothing visibly happens (all rows in the database are updated correctly) until I click another button anywhere on the page at which point all the changes are visibly updated in the Gridviews.

I've tried everything I can think of to fix this, no end of playing around with Update Panel options and positions, triggering an additional button click via JavaScript and any other solution I could find that seemed relevant, though none have got me any nearer to where I want to be.

If I've managed to convey my problems in such a way that anyone can understand I'd be grateful for insight, please ask questions if you feels I've not described something intelligibly.

Here are the three levels and page/user control/usercontrol:

Page:

```
<div id="divCustomerProductInput">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="udpSalesOrders" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plhCsCustomerproductInput" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

First User Control loaded into the placeholder above:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="udpSalesOrders" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always" >
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="plhProductionProcess"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Second User Control loaded into the placeholder above multiple times:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="udpPPI" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <%--  MANUFACTURE--%>
            <asp:GridView ID="gdvProductionProcessIngredients" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ingredient Description" ItemStyle-Width="21%" ControlStyle-Width="95%">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="txtIngredientDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IngredientDescription") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ingredient Code" ItemStyle-Width="14%" ControlStyle-Width="95%">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="txtIngredientCode" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RmId") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="From" ItemStyle-Width="10%" ControlStyle-Width="95%">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="txtParentDepartment" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ParentDepartment") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity (%)" ItemStyle-Width="10%" ControlStyle-Width="95%">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantityKg" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("OldestAncestorQuantityPercent") %>'
                                ForeColor="Black"></asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Input Cost / Kg (£)" ItemStyle-Width="13%" ControlStyle-Width="95%">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblCost" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("InputCostKg") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Yield (%)" ItemStyle-Width="10%" ControlStyle-Width="95%">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtYield" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Yield") %>' ForeColor="Black"></asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Output Cost / Kg (£)" ItemStyle-Width="14%" ControlStyle-Width="95%">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblCostPerKg" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("OutputCostKg") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="6%" ControlStyle-Width="95%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnDeleteIngredient" CommandName="REMOVE" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>'
                                CssClass="btn danger hover" runat="server" Text="Remove" /></ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Ok, here's the binding and updating code:

```
  Dim myCsProductProductionProcessIngredients As New v2.Model.CsProductProductionProcessIngredientCollection
    myCsProductProductionProcessIngredients.LoadByPPPId(_ProductProductionProcessId)

    Me.gdvProductionProcessIngredients.DataSource = myCsProductProductionProcessIngredients
    Me.gdvProductionProcessIngredients.DataBind()

    Me.udpPPI.Update()
```

Thanks, Korv

Comment: Please post some sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why my Update Panels didn't appear to be updating.

I was making an incorrect assumption about the page life-cycle and assuming that the event fired by the button click came before the page load.

I have now moved the Gridview population code to the Page_PreRender and everything is working as I intended.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to update a control in a separate update panel, change the updatepanel updatemode to "conditional", then when you need the panel updated you can call the Update method of the update panel.

For example if udpPPI is the panel you need to update when plhProductionProcess gets updated.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="udpPPI" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
```

Once the control in plhProductionProcess is updated call:

```
updPPI.Update()
```

Comment: I've now tried calling Update after every Place Holder is populated but i'm still not seeing the updated Gridviews after clicking the Save Button.

Comment: Can you post the code showing how you are binding the datagrids and updating the panels?

Comment: Yep, i'll do that on Monday, if you could check back then that would be cool